# Instantiate multiple times same PHP object

Tags: php, object, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to instantiate multiple times the same class in a simplified way other than this I have?

```
include ("php/functions.php");

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

require 'php/gapi.class.php';
$ga1 = new gapi('XXXX@gmail.com','XXXX');
$ga2 = new gapi('XXXX@gmail.com','XXXX');
$ga3 = new gapi('XXXX@gmail.com','XXXX');

$ga1->requestReportData( $report_id = XXXX, $dimension = array('browser'), $metrics = array('visitors','pageviews','visits'), $sort_metric = '-visitors', $filter = 'browser == Firefox || browser == Chrome || browser == Internet Explorer || browser == Safari || browser == Opera && visits > 10', $start_date = '2012-10-17' );

$ga2->requestReportData( $report_id = XXXX, $dimension = array('country'), $metrics = array('visitors','pageviews','visits'), $sort_metric = '-visits', $filter = 'country != (not set) && visits > 3', $start_date = '2012-10-17', null, null, 10 );

$date2 = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")-15, date("Y")));
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$ga3->requestReportData($report_id = XXXX, $dimension = array('date'), $metrics = array('pageviews','visits'), $sort_metric = array('date')  , $filter = '',$date2,$today, null,15);
```

PS: This code works as intended ... I was just wondering if there's a more efficient way to achieve this...

EDIT: To answer some questions made on some of the solutions provided, here's an example of application a couple hundred lines later on the same file:

```
      <h2 class="verde">By country (10 relvant results)</h2>
      [useless code ommited...]
      <tbody>
        <?php
        $tp = 0;
        foreach($ga2->getResults() as $r2){
          if($tp==10) break;
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $r2 ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $r2->getVisitors() ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $r2->getVisits() ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $r2->getPageviews() ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $tp++;
        }
        ?>
        <tr style="font-weight:700">
          <td><strong>TOTAIS</strong></td>
          <td><strong><?php echo $ga2->getVisitors() ?></strong></td>
          <td><strong><?php echo $ga2->getVisits() ?></strong></td>
          <td><strong><?php echo $ga2->getPageviews() ?></strong></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

I'm not sure if I can post links here ... but this code can be seen on http://jb.utad.pt/gapi/

Comment: your title and question does not match though....

Comment: are the email addresses or 2nd param different between ga1, ga2, ga3?

Comment: @Bot I'm assuming since the object is *gapi* `XXXX@gmail.com` is the email address and `XXXX` the corresponding password

Comment: Yup ... XXX are omissions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need `one object` to access a function. You may change the parameters passed to the function  according to your needs.

Having `multiple objects` of the same class, is not efficient code, as each object takes up that much extra memory.

Hence, you just need,

```
 $ga = new gapi('XXXX@gmail.com','XXXX');
 $ga->requestReportData( $report_id = XXXX, $dimension = array('browser'), $metrics =   array('visitors','pageviews','visits'), $sort_metric = '-visitors', $filter = 'browser == Firefox || browser == Chrome || browser == Internet Explorer || browser == Safari || browser == Opera && visits > 10', $start_date = '2012-10-17' );
 $ga->requestReportData( $report_id = XXXX, $dimension = array('country'), $metrics = array('visitors','pageviews','visits'), $sort_metric = '-visits', $filter = 'country != (not set) && visits > 3', $start_date = '2012-10-17', null, null, 10 );
 $date2 = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")-15, date("Y")));
 $today = date('Y-m-d');
 $ga->requestReportData($report_id = XXXX, $dimension = array('date'), $metrics = array('pageviews','visits'), $sort_metric = array('date')  , $filter = '',$date2,$today, null,15);
```

Comment: Problem is how to access the data, later on the page ... I need to access it to generate the code in the javascript (setting parameters for highcharts.js) and later on to generate HTML tables ... please see here: http://jb.utad.pt/gapi/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your email addresses are the same so you only need one object.

```
include ("php/functions.php");

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

require 'php/gapi.class.php';
$ga1 = new gapi('XXXX@gmail.com','XXXX');

$ga1->requestReportData( $report_id = XXXX, $dimension = array('browser'), $metrics = array('visitors','pageviews','visits'), $sort_metric = '-visitors', $filter = 'browser == Firefox || browser == Chrome || browser == Internet Explorer || browser == Safari || browser == Opera && visits > 10', $start_date = '2012-10-17' );

$ga1->requestReportData( $report_id = XXXX, $dimension = array('country'), $metrics = array('visitors','pageviews','visits'), $sort_metric = '-visits', $filter = 'country != (not set) && visits > 3', $start_date = '2012-10-17', null, null, 10 );

$date2 = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")-15, date("Y")));
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$ga1->requestReportData($report_id = XXXX, $dimension = array('date'), $metrics = array('pageviews','visits'), $sort_metric = array('date')  , $filter = '',$date2,$today, null,15);
```

there is no need to instantiate the same object multiple times.

Comment: A minor nitpick - this might be true, but only if the 'gapi' class isn't stateful in such a way that calling requestReportData would change it's state.

Answer (score 0):

Well, might help a bit:

```
$ga1 = new gapi('XXXX@gmail.com','XXXX');
$ga2 = clone $ga1;
```

Comment: why are you cloning the same object? If the data is the same, there isn't a need to create the same object multiple times just to run report data.

Comment: The data Google Analytis return for ga1 ga2 and ga3 is different! (Visitors by country, visits by browser and visitors and pageviews totals for the last 15 days)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest question is: **Does it make sense to instantiate the gapi class multiple times?** Is it a valid solution for the "problem" that you are trying to solve? In most cases, you could instantiate the same object thousands of times and it won't make that much of a difference (memory wise). The people who are telling you to consolidate all of your objects into one instance are completely missing the point of OOP. If it makes sense to have multiple instances of the same class, don't change that class for the sake of micro-optimization.

Comment: I'm just trying to perfect the code ... I thought that it could be better but wasn't sure ... that's why I asked :)

Comment: But your answer gives me a kind of relief feeling ... I wasn't that wrong when I coded this .. never the less ... I got the feeling inside that could be done a better way!

Answer (score 0):

In your code-example actually these calls are superfluous:

```
$ga1->requestReportData( $report_id = XXXX, $dimension = array('browser'), $metrics = array('visitors','pageviews','visits'), $sort_metric = '-visitors', $filter = 'browser == Firefox || browser == Chrome || browser == Internet Explorer || browser == Safari || browser == Opera && visits > 10', $start_date = '2012-10-17' );
$ga2->requestReportData( $report_id = XXXX, $dimension = array('country'), $metrics = array('visitors','pageviews','visits'), $sort_metric = '-visits', $filter = 'country != (not set) && visits > 3', $start_date = '2012-10-17', null, null, 10 );
$ga3->requestReportData($report_id = XXXX, $dimension = array('date'), $metrics = array('pageviews','visits'), $sort_metric = array('date')  , $filter = '',$date2,$today, null,15);
```

Because no return values are stored. So you can just leave them out. That then turns out that the three objects `$ga1` to `$ga3` are not needed, too. So yes, you can really compact it and spare any of those objects. Also the datetime calculation is not needed.

Your new file:

```
<?php
/* space intentionally left blank */
?>
```

Moral of the story: As long as you don't show *why* you call these functions, it can not be said how to improve the code.

1. What happens with the returned data?
2. Are you querying different API accounts?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 1) The returned data is used in a jQuery inline code (3 times to set parameters to highcharts.js... by browser, by country, and ) and later on ... in the HTML code (edited my question with an example) 2) Always querying only 1 API account. Can see the full code viewing source of http://jb.utad.pt/gapi/